# Two untrusting people want to come up with a random number

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, quantum-cryptography, quantum-key-distribution

Two people want to come up with a random number. They don't trust each other nor any third party. What are the known solutions to this problem?

I am a quantum cryptography student and am currently working quantum random number generation. Any solutions, either classical or quantum are welcome.

EDIT

Ok so here's what I understood by reading through some papers. Assume two mistrusting parties want to come up with a random bit. In the classical scenario (without assuming computational hardness) the task is impossible. In the quantum scenario, there are two variants; strong and weak versions. If the desired outcome of each party is **not** known it's called the strong version and vice-versa. The strong version has a non-zero bound on its bias whereas the weak version can have an arbitrarily small bias.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.13283.pdf

Comment: Not an answer, but just to help your search : this problem is called coin-flipping

Comment: Thank you for that. That really helped!

Answer (score 5):

The random number required is an integer between 0 and $\ell$. Each person picks a random number $x_i$ between 0 and $\ell$, and each person picks an $n$-bit random blinding factor $b_i$ where $n\geq 128$ and $n$ must be agreed in advance. Each then announces a hash commitment calculated as $H(b \mathbin\|x)$. They then each open their commitments by announcing their values of $b$ and $x$, and calculate their random number as $$x_1 + x_2\ \pmod \ell.$$ This is quantum-secure if the hash and choice of $n$ are together quantum-secure.

As @poncho points out, the person that opens their commitment last can simulate a failure to complete the protocol if they are unhappy with the particular shared random value that would be generated during that invocation of the protocol. This could be a problem particularly if $\ell$ is small.

One way of avoiding this problem is to ensure that there is a forfeit for failure to complete the protocol. For example, each person could deposit funds with a trusted arbitrator that would confiscate those funds from the person that did not complete the protocol. The forfeit should equal or exceed the maximum possible gain from simulating a failure.

Comment: One attack against this protocol is a 'simulated failure' attack; suppose Alice picked $x_1$ and Bob picked $x_2$; they go through the protocol and Alice opens her commitment to $x_1$.  Now, Bob see he doesn't like the result $x_1 + x_2 \bmod \ell$, and so he simulates a failure (network failure, computer reboot, whatever).  This can be addressed by a metaprotocol; it may be important that you do so

Comment: @poncho thanks, great point

Comment: What if there is a really error? Why a honest person should lose fund in this case?

Comment: @kelalaka An honest person should resume (rather than restart or abandon) the protocol as soon as technical difficulties are resolved, and there will be no forfeit. A dishonest person would want to abandon the protocol and never resume it.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.102.022414) solves at least partially your problem.

Comment: We call this as link only answer and consider as a comment. Could you a little explain what does this paper?

Comment: This was really helpfull... @kelalaka I will try to add a comment once I understand it

Comment: Ok so here's what I understood by reading through some papers. Assume two mistrusting parties want to come up with a random bit. In the classical scenario (without assuming computational hardness) the task is impossible. In the quantum scenario, there are two variants; strong and weak versions. If the desired outcome of each party is **not** known it's called the strong version and vice-versa. The strong version has a non-zero bound on its bias whereas the weak version can have an arbitrarily small bias.

Answer (score 1):

Manuel Blaum looked this issue in 1981 in [Coin Flipping By Telephone A Protocol For Solving Impossible Problems](https://sci-hub.st/10.1145/1008908.1008911)

The technical details are on the paper. This protocol guarantees those (from the paper, bolds are mind);

1. If either participant following protocol **does not catch the other cheating, he or she can be sure that the coins each have exactly 50-50 independent chance** to come up heads (provable under the reasonable assumption that factoring is hard.
2. If **either participant catches the other cheating, he or she can prove it to a judge** (this assumes that all messages are sent signed).
3. After Bob flips coins to Alice, she knows which coins came up heads, which tails. **He should have absolutely NO idea how they came up** (not even a good guess).
4. **After the sequence of coin flips, Alice should be able to prove to Bob which coins came up heads, which tails**.